# Why can't elements and atoms be separated by physical and chemical means?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elements

> Our textbook tells us ''that elements and atoms cannot be separated by chemical and physical methods. He says only atoms can be separated by nuclear methods.''

First of all, I would like to start my question as follows. We call the smallest unit of an element an atom. We call a collection of single types of atoms with the same number of protons an element. At this point, let's consider, for example, the molecular element oxygen. Isn't separating this element into its molecules or separating the molecules into their atoms decomposing this element?

My other question is: isn't removing an electron from an atom a decomposition? So, when we say decomposition in chemistry, do we mean extracting different types of substances from one substance?

Edit:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element

> Kimyasal element, kimyasal reaksiyonlarla başka maddelere parçalanamayan kimyasal bir maddedir. Kimyasal elementi oluşturan temel parçacık atomdur.

Edit:2

> We all know that atoms can never be created or destroyed by any physical or chemical method. Any type of atom can only be converted from one form to another.
> Elements are substances that contain only one type of atom. As we have previously stated that atoms cannot be destroyed in a physical or chemical reaction, elements cannot be broken down into simpler substances. Breaking down an element gives us atoms of the same element, so no new substance is obtained.
> For example, water actually consists of two main elements: hydrogen and oxygen. Therefore, water is a compound that can be broken down into simpler substances such as oxygen and hydrogen. However, we cannot separate the elements hydrogen and oxygen into simpler substances.
> Therefore, we cannot break down elements into simpler substances.

https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/can-elements-be-broken-down-class-11-chemistry-cbse-60235daff865ac1e018d5242

Comment: Oxygen can be an element, as it is the collection of atoms having 8 protons. The same name is usually used for describing the molecules $\ce{O2}$ made of two atoms oxygen. But oxygen cannot be called a molecular element, as you are stating. Oxygen is either an element, or a molecule. Not both simultaneously. And removing an electron from an atom is not a decomposition. It is an ionization. the word decomposition is used when separating one or several atoms from a molecule.

Comment: @Maurice Well, can't we separate an element with a single atomic structure, such as iron, into its atoms? Wouldn't this be segregation?

Comment: Either your textbook by "separation" means breaking up atoms, or you translated it badly. No matter what you do with iron, it's still iron, be it liquid, gas or plasma. Unless you manage to cause a nuclear reaction.

Comment: @Mithoron Isn't separating an atomic element into atoms a decomposition in chemistry? The expressions in the book cannot be decomposed into simpler units. How can the atom be separated into simpler units with nuclear energy? Should a substance with different properties emerge as a result of this separation? For example, if we divide the molecular element oxygen in nature into its atoms, wouldn't this be decomposed into simpler units?

Comment: @Maurice Isn't oxygen O2 an element with a molecular structure? Let's also consider an element with an atomic structure: iron. Isn't separating the element iron into its atoms a decomposition? Or do we not take this as separation because atoms show the properties of the element? Finally, if we consider 1 iron atom, is this 1 atom also an iron element? In other words, aren't the concepts of 1 atom and element the same concept?

Comment: Asking on CH SE site should not be the first choice to find answers. It should be rather the last choice, after thorough consulting available offline and online resources before asking. Include compact summary of this research as the starting point.  If you found nothing, provide what/where you were searching for.  // This way you will learn the independent studying and saving resources of people telling you, what you could find on your own. Additionally, such a question would be a bigger contribution to the community.

Comment: This is a question about English, not about chemistry.

Comment: It was not an answer, but a comment. Btw metals do not have atomic structure. If they had had one, their melting and boiling points would have been very low, lower than for many organic compounds. They are interconnected by metallic bonds.

Comment: If things connected by metallic bonds are not atoms, what are they? What I mean by atomic structure is a structure made up of atoms. Also, please keep your comments that constantly correct me to yourself. I may make mistakes. My English is not as good as yours. Please keep this in mind when commenting.

Comment: What book is this? Could you provide a full citation?

Comment: @BuckThorn It is the national education book in this country. While explaining the properties of elements and atoms, he says that they cannot be separated into simpler units by physical and chemical means. This information is also available on wikipedia and on English websites.

Comment: Well, that's nonsense, depending on how you define "separate", "units", "simpler", "chemica methodsl" and "physical methods". If you use standard definitions, it's nonsense.There is something called "sub-atomic structure". It's basic knowledge that atoms consist of nuclei and electrons, that nuclei consist of neutrons and protons (which in turn are also divisible), that a process called radioactivity allows conversion between elements, etc. Atoms might be defined as the simplest or smallest chemical structures. There might be better definitions.

Comment: @BuckThorn The book says, Atoms cannot be broken down physically or chemically. However, with nuclear energy, atoms are broken down into simpler units. However, the book states that elements cannot be separated by chemical and physical methods. The point I'm asking is, can't we separate an element into its atoms? In the source I have given below, it says that since elements are composed of the same type of atoms, separating elements into atoms will not create a new substance, chemistry does not call this decomposition.

Comment: @BuckThorn https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/can-elements-be-broken-down-class-11-chemistry-cbse-60235daff865ac1e018d5242

Comment: "Separate" and "decompose" have different meanings (and even individually can be used to mean different things). I understand decompose to mean "to break down". Separate means to bring apart. A single atom cannot be decomposed chemically. Two atoms can be separated from each other, however. The term "element" requires some care (see the answer you received). If you have matter in elemental form, all atoms in that matter are of the same type and cannot be decomposed chemically into other types of atom.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the term element has several meanings in chemistry, depending on context. It is mandatory and essential to clarify in any discussion, which of meanings you have in mind.

- An element(1) is an atom, a ion, or a nucleus itself, having the particular number of protons in its nucleus.
- An element(2) is a molecule or molecular ion consisting of atoms of the same element(1). Such a molecule can be huge, if you consider graphite or diamond.
- An element(3) is a substance, consisting of element(1) or element(2), with all atoms of the same proton number. Various forms of element(3) are called [allotropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropy) of element(1).
- An element (3a) is any of element(1,2,3)
- An element(4) is an element(1) integrated in molecules of compounds or substances.
- An element(5) is a basic building block of a more complex system or structure.

---

Element(4) can be chemically isolated as element(3).

Element(3) can be chemically(*) or physically separated to atoms/ions of element(1), in many cases via element(2).

An element(1) cannot be further divided by chemical means. As a molecular entity is the smallest particle of a compound, still having it's properties, an atom/ion/nucleus of element(1) is the smallest particle of the element(3a), having still its properties and can be still recombined to element(2,3).

$\ce{Hg(l)->Hg(g)}$ is decomposing of element(3) to a set of atoms=element(1).
$\ce{C(s)->C2(g)}$ is decomposing of element(3) to element(2).
$\ce{O2(g)->2 O(g)}$ is decomposing of element(2) to element(1).

Further dividing is possible, involving physical methods of breaking or transforming the nucleus, forming one or more nuclei of different elements(1).

It does not mean one element(1) consists of other elements(1). It means the building blocks of elements(1), subatomic particles protons, neutrons and electrons, form different elements(1) by different ways in different numbers they get together via strong and electromagnetic force.

(*) - Chemistry is a part of physics, focusing on mutual interactions of atomic  electrons and their implication for matter behaviour on micro and macros scale.

Comment: As far as I understand, there is a misconception here. Now let's think of an element with a 2-atom molecular structure. Here, this element can be decomposed into atoms, or even into simpler substances through a nuclear reaction after the atoms. However, since the atoms of an element show the same chemical properties as the element, chemistry does not consider this as a dissociation.

Comment: But if we separate a compound chemically, we can reveal 2 or more elements. And the chemical and physical properties of these elements can be very different from the properties of the compound. So chemistry takes this as an example of dissociation. At least that's how textbooks get it?

Comment: Where exactly did you get that O2 -> 2 O is not dissociation? HCl is a compound and can be dissociated to atomic or molecular chlorine and oxygen. O2 is not compound, it is one of allotropes of oxygen, that can be dissociated to atomic oxygen.

Comment: See my update. By definition written on Wikipedia and all other textbooks and chemistry sites. Elements cannot be broken down into simpler substances by chemical or physical means.

Comment: Avoid using screenshots instead of copy pasted text or easy retyping. // Elements(1) cannot be. Elements(2,3) can be broken to elements(1,2). Context rules. E.g. O3, O2 and O,  or S8, S2 and S are different substances, being different allotropes of respective elements. // You consistently avoid distinguishing of meanings of "element" what leads to vague statements.

Comment: Could you please check the new update?

Comment: It is not correct very much much.

Answer (score 0):

One way to discern a *separation by physical means* and a *separation by chemical means* is to monitor if (valence)* electrons are redistributed, or not.

By this criterion, passing for instance a mixture of water and sand through filter paper is purely physical: sand remains sand, and water wasn't changed and still is water.  On the other hand, the electrolysis of molten sodium chloride (i.e. mobile ions of $\ce{Na^+}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$) to yield elemental sodium in one part, and elemental chlorine in an other part of the [Downs cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downs_cell) is a chemical process; here, the sodium cations obtain an electron by chloride anions; you converted the compound *sodium chloride* (a salt) into new compounds *sodium* (a metal) and *chlorine* (a gas).

The separation of elemental** nitrogen gas and elemental oxygen gas by fractional distillation, for instance while running a [Linde process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampson%E2%80%93Linde_cycle) equally is a physical process: there is no transfer of electrons between the atoms, no old/already existing chemical bonds between the atoms are broken, and no new chemical bonds between atoms are formed.  This invalidates the statement elements couldn't be separated by physical means alone.

* Except [nuclear chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_chemistry), most chemistry involves the most accessible electrons in highest atomic/molecular orbitals.  For instance, the reaction of sodium and chlorine to yield sodium chloride is about the transfer of sodium's electron in the $3s$ orbital into a $3p$ orbital of chlorine with preservation of the $1s^2 2s^2 2p^6$ configuration of neon.  Hence some tables abbreviate the report of the electron configuration e.g., for chlorine with $\ce{Ne}\ 3s^2 3p^5$.

** "element" as in case (3) of the answer by @Poutnik

Comment: I understood how to separate a compound into its elements by chemical means. But can't we separate an element into its atoms? Can't an atom be a simpler substance than an element? Or are we saying that since atoms represent that element chemically and physically, separating an element into its atoms does not mean decomposing it into a simpler unit? Again, what do we mean by decomposing an atom into its simpler units? When we split the atom nuclearly, do we create 2 different types of atoms?

Comment: Some elements can occur as isolated atoms (metals, helium); other only as polyatomic molecules (e.g., nitrogen). The nuclear split of atoms is [nuclear fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission) as e.g., in an nuclear power plant. Energies involved are much greater than typical bench chemistry. But today chemists know than an atom itself consists of smaller (subatomic) particles, [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle).  *These* (at present state of research) are recognized as the smallest units of matter.